# my code is not progressing and in the out put section its showing "running" whenever i try to take input from user in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, user-input

The code in which i want to take input from the user is not progressing and showing running in the output section,but any other code where i am not taking any input from user is running fine.This problem i am facing in my visual studio code application.I am using it in windows 10 64 bit with minGW compiler.I have installed necessary extensions for c/c++.Any suggestions how to solve this problem?
[ss of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4uY0.png)

it is the ss of that page and look i waited for 1700
+sec but it didn't gave any results.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int x = 89;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please include the code as text in the question

Comment: do you have any area selected in the terminal?  Doing so suspends operation of the underlying program.

Comment: no area is selected in terminal

Comment: Did you provide any user input your program was expecting (line 8) ?

Comment: All questions here should have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. Can you [edit] this question, removing and replacing all links and images with all relevant information as plain text? All code must meet all requirements of a [mre]. You can find many other questions here that explain everything in plain text, please use them as an example for how your question should look.

Comment: Works fine https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php Input 123 output 123

Comment: its working fine in online compilers but not working on my system

Comment: If your program takes user input, the user needs to provide some input. What input did you provide and how?

Comment: If you know that it is basically working, just not in your environment tell us more about it. How exactly do you build? How exactly do you execute? How exactly do you provide the needed input? Where exactly do you expect the output? Did you try local alternatives? Other than visual code. E.g. simpler editor, explicit building with gcc and explicit call from shell/prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the input. When your program starts, type a number in the terminal. Then press the enter. Your program prints the number in the next line and then exits.
[image]

Comment: yeah its working in terminal but why not working in output

Comment: i tried it in terminal and its working fine

Comment: Output is not intended toward user inputs. It usually shows you build instructions, test results, and other output-like content. In another word, you can not do input in the output panel. It is not designed for that.

Comment: Think of output pannel as a way that IDE communicates with you. It is not about the code you write or its execution. Output pannel belongs to IDE itself and your IDE uses it.